# LUIS API call "example utterances - Review labeled examples" returns 404 but 401 when called via the API test console

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to get "example utterances - Review labeled example" from the LUIS api. As explained here: https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0a

But this call returns a "404 - Resource not found"

> https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/[appid]/versions/0.1/examples?skip=0&take=100

When I try the same call via the testing console...

> https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0a/console

... it returns "401 - Access Denied" with the message

> The example utterances - Review labeled examples Operation under LUIS Programmatic APIs v2.0 API is not supported with the current subscription key and pricing tier LUIS.S0."

I've been at it for over a day, trying to create/update/delete autoring resources from Azure. Selected different pricing tiers, but I'm ending up with the same results.

I even tried deleting my LUIS account in an effort to restart from scratch but also that seems impossible. I keep logging back in to my "deleted" account.

Some help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you replace [appid] in the call that is producing the 404? Can you provide cURL statements for both (with the personally identifying info replaced)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use LUIS service in westeurope , pls try the steps below :

1. Go to Azure portal and create an LUIS service : 
   [image]

After this task completed , you will see two services : 
[image] . The first one is service related and the second one which end with "-Authoring" is used for management . Lick the second one => keys , copy either of two keys and we will use it later .

2. Go to [LUIS Europe portal](https://eu.luis.ai/applications) select your LUIS Authoring service which just created  as Authoring Resource so that we can use this endpoint to manage your LUIS service.
   [image]

Create a new app for test APIs : 
[image]

After this app created , we can test APIs you need, you can find app id and version here:
[image]

Try the API :

[image]

Hope it helps .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your flow and that worked perfectly. Then I tried  my original LUIS app again and it also works. Now, I don't know what I did wrong before I posted this question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that may be limiting you that you should double check.

**First**

Are you including a `subscription-key` in the API call. Making a call to the below endpoint (with the correct AppId included) but with no `subscription-key` in the header results in a 404.

[image]

However, if I include the `subscriptionId`, it does route correctly allowing for a query to be made.

[image]

[image]

**Second**

Check that the `subscription-key` is correct. If you supply a `subscription-key` but it is incorrect, this will result in a 401.

**Third**

Check that you created your Azure LUIS resource in the region you believe you have. If you are trying to access the API from `westeurope` but your resource is in `westus`, this will result in a 404.

**Lastly**

Consider flushing your browser's cache. If you say you are still able to access a deleted resource, you may be using cached data giving the appearance of still accessible resources. This could be affecting other areas such as your API calls.

Hope of help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your example you're calling the apps endpoint. This works perfect for me. It's the "example utterances - Review labeled example" API endpoint I'm having trouble with. I think I have created Azure LUIS resource every possible way. I even tried westus to make sure that, indeed, doesn't work either. It's the LUIS account I can't delete. The AZURE resources take some time to refresh  but they delete nicely.